# Error: &P cannot be used as a function

Tags: c++, function

I have this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>

double PVfut(int n, int r)
{
    double P[n];
    for(int m=0;m<n;m++){
        cout<<"Value:"<<endl;
        cin>>P[m];
        }

    double PV;
    double p;
    for(int m=0;m<n;m++){
        p*=(1+r);
        PV+=P(m)/(p);
    }
}
main(){
    cout<<PVfut(2,2)<<endl;
}
```

I encounter an error saying that `&P cannot be used as a function` when calling `PVfut`.

What is the problem?

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic due to a simple typographical error.

Comment: Also, `main()` is wrong in C++ (not so in <= C90). Use `int main()`.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `P[m]` instead of `P(m)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue comes from

```
for(int m=0;m<n;m++){
        p*=(1+r);
        PV+=P(m)/(p);
    }
```

I assume you meant to put `P[m]` instead of `P(m)`?